# MPAndroidChart android studio gradle compile error

Tags: android, compilation, gradle, android-studio, mpandroidchart

My IDE: Android Studio 0.8.12
Gradle version: 2.1
MPAndroidChart: 1.6.5

When I use MPAndroidChart in a demo, it works fine. But when I integrate it with my project, there are some problems:

[image]

Eg: I can access methods and fields from **BarChart** and its super class **BarLineChartBase**, but I cannot access them from super-super class **Chart**.

**FYI**: The project can ignore that error and build-run at my device.

Comment: does it help if you clean+rebuild project?
or reimport project?

Comment: @BartoszBilicki  No, I have tried everything I could to solve this problem, but failed. I even delete all .iml files and .idea/ folder then import, but nothing effect.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in my setup. A few things you can look at, though none of them seem really likely: 1. Are you sure you're using the right version of this library? 2. How are you including the library? Maybe if you update your answer it will shed a little light on it. 3. Clear caches and restart? I hesitate to suggest this, because it's overused by a lot of people who cargo-cult it as the answer to everything, but it's worth a shot. 4. Anything interesting in the logs?

Comment: @ScottBarta Maybe it's android studio's bug, even I encounter this error, I still can build and run at my device. I've tried too much ways, finally decide to write my own chart use android canvas, and it nearly finish now.

Comment: It's an Android Studio bug. I see a lot of reports of various things like this on Stack Overflow, but haven't been able to pin anything down to file a solid bug so it can be fixed -- these things are so slippery that it's hard to get a solid reproducible case. If you have a minimal project that reproduces this issue that you could share, it would be of enormous help.

Comment: @ScottBarta I will try, but not very sure can reproduce it in another project.